# JavaScript async problems with EJS, json-schema-to-typescript, writefilesync, and renamesync

Tags: typescript, async-await, ejs, jsonschema

My goal is to transform JSON Schema into Typescript code and write it to a file.

Normally **json-schema-to-typescript** can handle this directly, but this is just one step in a much larger code generation program, so I'm trying to get it to work with my existing setup, where **EJS** renders a file, that goes through **prettier**, that is written to a temp directory, that is moved to the final directory once all the files are done.

(I don't think **prettier** is the issue here, but I'm leaving it in because it is part of the overall process.)

The problem is **renameSync** is failing with an error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'tempfile' -> 'file.ts'`.

I create a repo with all the code that demonstrates this problem. Set it up with `setup.sh` and run it with `go.sh`.

https://github.com/jmcguire/ejs-json-schema-to-typescript-writefile-problem

(Note: This is a severely reduced version of a more complicated piece of code I'm working on, but it does demonstrate the exact problem in one typescript file and two EJS files: index.ts, file.ejs, and interface.ejs.)

Here are the three files.

**index.ts**

```
import { writeFileSync, renameSync } from "fs";
import ejs from "ejs";
import { compile } from "json-schema-to-typescript";
import prettier from "prettier";

const schemas = [
  {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      id: {
        type: "integer",
        format: "int64",
      },
    },
    modelName: "thingOne",
  },
];

export function convertJsonSchemaToTypescript(jsonSchema: any) {
  return compile(jsonSchema, jsonSchema.modelName);
}

function renderMyFile(fileIn: string, fileOut: string) {
  ejs.renderFile(
    fileIn,
    {
      schemas,
      convertJsonSchemaToTypescript,
      // in the real program I pass in a pile of data, and a pile of functions
      // to operate on that data. the templates decide how to use them all.
      // here I'm only passing in one piece of data and one function.
    },
    { async: true },
    async (err, renderedFileAsAString) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      const prettierRenderedString = prettier.format(
        await renderedFileAsAString,
        { parser: "typescript" }
      );

      writeFileSync(fileOut, await prettierRenderedString);
    }
  );
}

renderMyFile("file.ejs", "tempfile");

// I know this looks strange, but in my actual program I write everything to a
// temp directory, then move it all over to its final directory once it's
// finished, and I want to simulate that here.
renameSync("tempfile", "file.ts");
```

**file.ejs**

```
<% for ( let i=0; i < schemas.length; i++) { %>
  <%- await include("interface", { schema: schemas[i] }) %>
<% } %>
```

**interface.ejs**

```
<%- await convertJsonSchemaToTypescript(schema) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your functions are async so you need to call first with await:

```js
(async () => {
    await renderMyFile("file.ejs", "tempfile");
    await renameSync("tempfile", "file.ts");
})();
```

You can omit the wrapper async function if you can use top-level await.

And second thing is that if `ejs.renderFile` return a promise when the async render is used then you need to return that promise from the function, otherwise this will not work.